# jquery script not functioning correctly in IE8 - perfect in FF

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, hide, switch-statement

Can anyone help me with this jquery script - I am not a programmmer and have been given this script but the writer can't help....

I have a script that functions perfctly in FF but in IE8 something weird happens:

- what should be case 1 will choose case 2 (or 3 if coming from case 3)
- what should becase 2 will choose case 3
- what should becase 3 will choose case 2 (or 3 if coming from case 1)

does this make sense?

anyway this is the script-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function hideall() {
    $('#li_9').hide();
    $('#li_56').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    hideall();

    $("#form_40 input[@name='element_59']").change(function() {
        hideall();

        switch($(this).val()) {
            case '1' :
                $('#li_9').show();
                break;

            case '2':
                $('#li_9').show();
                $('#li_56').show();
            break;

            case '3' :
                $('#li_56').show();
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not noticing anything wrong. Can you post a link to the page/site that exhibits the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumped out at me was

```
input[@name='element_59']
```

I looked through the jQuery API and didn't see any references to what "@" did before the name.  You may want to verify you are using it correctly.

Other than that you can make some improvements in your selectors by chaining your show and hide functions like this:

```
$('#li_9, #li_56').hide();

$('#li_9, #li_56').show();
```

The other thing is your example above doesn't close out the 'change' method or the 'ready' event. I'm assuming this is just how it's posted here.

Comment: The `@` was used in versions of jQuery prior to `1.3`. OP must be using an older version, otherwise the `.change()` event wouldn't fire at all.

Comment: Of course it is. I'm saying that with the `@`, the `.change()` would fail completely if OP was using a newer version of jQuery. The handler is firing, so the `@` isn't the issue.